# Необходима помощь с cmd-скриптами

Tags: bash, cmd

Необходимо после ввода директории с клавиатуры, пройтись по всем папкам внутри директории, найти в них txt-файлы и перекодировать их в utf-8

```
 @Echo off
 for /r C:\Users\bearf\Desktop\books /d %%f in (*) do (
 copy C:\Users\bearf\Desktop\books\cicl.bat "%%f"
 call :cicl.bat
 )
 pause>nul
 exit
```

cicl.bat:

```
@Echo off
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
echo %%i
powershell /nop "[IO.File]::WriteAllText('%%i',[IO.File]::ReadAllText('%%i',[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('cp866')),[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('UTF-8'))"
)
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж вы все равно используете Powershell, то почему бы все не сделать на нем.

```
using namespace System.IO
using namespace System.Text

$cp866 = [Encoding]::GetEncoding('cp866')
$utf8 = [Encoding]::UTF8

$path = "C:\Users\bearf\Desktop\books"
#$path = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input path'

foreach ($file in [Directory]::GetFiles($path, "*.txt", [SearchOption]::AllDirectories)))
{
    echo $file
    [File]::WriteAllText($file, [File]::ReadAllText($file, $cp866), $utf8)
}
```